# How to save movie clips as an album in flash/as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am developing a color book in flash cs3 and actionscript 3. The application will work like this. The user will change the color of the movie clip. Then they will save it in an album by clicking on a button(for example 'add to my album'). So, the image should be saved within the flash application so that next time if the user opens the application it should be available in the album. 
I have finished the coloring part. But I don't know how to use a save button to save the colored image in the same flash application.
How to achieve it? Is there any useful tutorial? or Can someone give me an idea?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this being developed for Web, AIR, mobile, or some combination?  That may make a pretty big difference in which direction you take.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this, hopefully it will help.
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/filereference_class_as3.html